# Jquery clone div inside form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to duplicate a div with its content, inside a form. But everytime it clones outside the form.

```
<form>
    <div class="avail" style="border:1px solid #cccccc; padding:3px;">
        <div id="id">Tip dispozitiv:
            <select name="tip" id="tip" class="tip" cnt="senzori">
                <option value="NA" selected="selected">---</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <select id="senzori" name="senzori" style="border:1px solid #cccccc;">
                <option selected="selected">---</option>
            </select>x
            <input type="text" name="ctr_bucati" size="2" value="1">Bucati
            <div style="display:inline-block; margin-left:300px;"><a href="#" id="rem" class="rem">X</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="+" id="copy" />
```

```js
$("#copy").click(function (e) {
    var avails = $(".avail");
    var cnt = avails.length + 1;
    avails.eq(0).clone().insertBefore(this).find("div").attr("id", "id" + cnt).find("#senzori").attr("id", "senzori" + cnt);
    $("#id" + cnt).find("#tip").attr("cnt", "senzori" + cnt);
    $("#senzori" + cnt).find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="NA">---</option>').val('NA');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Any clue how i can make it stay in the same form and not colone after ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `insertBefore(this)`

use `.appendTo(avails.parent())`

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cwqa3ffa/)

Answer (score 1):

add an id to your form and append the div to the form

```
<form id="myform">

var myDiv = $(".avail");

$("#myform").append(myDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can modify HTML rather than JS code, by moving "+" button into the form:

```
<form>
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="submit" value="+" id="copy" />
</form>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yoxn0j4g/